# sql join and fetching rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
id      dept         Person       Rating
1       ece            p1           R1  
2       ece            p2           M2     
3       eee            P6           R2             
4       eee            p2           R2
5       Civil          P7           R1
6       Civil          P3           R1
7       Civil          P8           M2
8       Mech           p7           R3
9       Mech           P3           R3
```

I need all Id's whose Ratings is M2 and their colleagues Rating is R1 in a particular dept.  Note: Each dept may have difft ratings.

```
**Output**: id
        2
        7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        a.id
FROM    (
            SELECT  * FROM YourTable WHERE Rating = 'M2'
        )a
        JOIN YourTable b
            ON a.Dept = b.Dept
WHERE   b.Rating = 'R1'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select id
from myTable t1
where Rating = 'M2'
and exists (select * from myTable t2 
  where t1.dept = t2.dept and t2.Rating='R1');
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c078b/1)

Comment: This is the most efficient way out of the answers so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT t1.id
FROM myTable t1 LEFT JOIN
        myTable t2 ON t1.dept = t2.dept
WHERE t1.Rating = 'M2' AND t2.Rating = 'R1';
```